# Center Logo in line with Menu - Avada Theme

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to have my logo inline with my menu and centered.

3 menu's - logo - 3 menu's

I am also trying to get the sticky header to do this.

I have been trying to modify the css and header.php, but I am having issues.

Can someone please help me?

My website is http://wintandkidd.net

Comment: So what exactly is your issue? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I would like to get the logo centered and in the line of the menus.
menu 1, menu 2, menu 3, logo, menu 4, menu 5, menu 6

Comment: I am also trying to do this in the sticky header - the header that is on top when you scroll down the front page. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I was already able to do this on my sticky header and on the header itself but it did not look good. Thank you for those who looked into this. I am working to put the logo within the slider below the menu which would make the site look better.